# Can I use \t in find() in C++?

Tags: c++, find

My program doesn't work as it should, so I was wondering if I can use `\t` to find tabs with `find()` in a text in C++.

Comment: Yes, you can. Remember to use `'\t'` and not `"\t"`, for a single character.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str ="line1\tline2";
int k = str.find('\t');
if(k > 0)
    cout<<"yes\n";
else
    cout<<"No\n";
```

you can use `find('\t')`

Comment: `int k` may have an implementation defined value, when converted from the return value of `string::find`. For portable standard compliance: `auto k = str.find('\t'); if(k != string::npos)`

Answer (score 1):

Formal :

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <string>         // std::string

int main ()
{

std::string str="This\tTab";
char tab = '\t';

std::size_t found = str.find(tab);
if (found!=std::string::npos)
std::cout << "Tab found at: " << found << '\n';

return 0;
}
```